caching with unstable_cache is not working
After several attempts and thinking I had a mistake in my code, I tried the exemple from official next documentation about unstable_cache.
const getCachedUser = unstable_cache(
  async (id) => getEmployerByAuthID(id),
  ["my-app-user"],
);

export default async function MyProfileInfo() {
  const { authUser, userData } = await getAuthUser({
    redirectionOnError: pages.login,
  });

  let employer;
  try {
    employer = await getCachedUser(authUser.id);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}


export const getEmployerByAuthID = async (userId) => {
  console.log("dans getEmployerByAuthID", userId);
  const employer = await db.query.Employer.findFirst({
    columns: { userId: false }, // We don't want to disclose the auth credentials
    where: (employer, { eq }) => eq(employer.userId, userId),
  });

  if (!employer) throw new Error("No employer found");

  return employer;
};

Inside getEmployerByAuthID, I have a console log to see if the function has been called or not.
And it's always executed whereas I was expecting the result to come from the cache.
Is unstable_cache still working? I don't want to switch to nextjs15 right now.
Or is there some configuration to make it work?
[EDIT]
In order to avoid any hidden mistakes from my side, I simply copied pasted the full code from the next exemple like this:
export default async function MyProfileInfo() {
  const getCachedUser = unstable_cache(
    async () => {
      console.log("cache miss");
      return { id: authUser.id };
    },
    [authUser.id], // add the user ID to the cache key
    {
      tags: ["users"],
      revalidate: 60,
    },
  );

  let employer;
  try {
    console.log("get employer from component");
    const employer = await getCachedUser(authUser.id);
    console.log(employer);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    // return redirect(pages.myAccount);
    return;
  }
}

And I still get the "cache missed" consoled every time

I am suggesting you to check the things below

Caching key (it should be unique as in my view)
Function signature : as unstable_cache needs to work with async function soake sure your function return proper data which is cacheable

here are some basics i updated, you can try and check
const getCachedUser = unstable_cache(
  async (id) => getEmployerByAuthID(id),
  (id) => [`my-app-user-${id}`], // Cache key based on the user ID
);


export default async function MyProfileInfo() {
  const { authUser, userData } = await getAuthUser({
    redirectionOnError: pages.login,
  });

  let employer;
  try {
    // Ensure that this ID is correct and the cache is properly utilized
    employer = await getCachedUser(authUser.id);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}`


the documentation explicitly says that the keyparts is optional, unstable_cache already uses the argument to create a unique cache key. Since my argument is a primitive, it should work fine as a unique identifier. Nonetheless, I still have tried your code and not better.
And yes I return an async function. I edited my question to show what I'm returning.
